# Internationalization of daterangepicker in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, daterangepicker

I'm using a bootstrap-daterangepicker-rails gem in my app.
I18n.locale can be chosen from English or Ukrainian on the header.
I can't find the solution how to make a pop-up calendar be shown in that language which is chosen for the app.

My code in app/assets/javascripts/mini_scripts.js :

```
$('#daterange').datepicker({
  format: "mm/yyyy",
  startView: 1,
  minViewMode: 1,
  language: "uk"
});
```

It works great when language: "uk" or language: "en". But how to make it work accordingly to I18n.locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#daterange').datepicker({
  format: "mm/yyyy",
  startView: 1,
  minViewMode: 1,
  language: "<%= I18n.locale %>"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Any ideas on how to make it works in js file? Because the code is located in app/assets/javascripts/mini_scripts.js

Comment: While answering a question, please provide some kind of explanation to support your answer.

Comment: @Nadiya, I'd use a `gon` gem